# How to Remove Spam Links to Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics-spam

My hacked WP site has been scanned and cleansed.

However, the site is still getting a high volume of requests to non-existent pages on my domain

eg. `3095/lissome/4125_campward.jp`

What I do not know is :

1. How to stop getting these requests for "spam links" (is this the correct name for these links ? )
2. Where are these links located ? Because I know that my site has nothing to do with Japanese products !
3. Why would the hacker put thousands of these non-existent links back to my site ?

I have looked at Google Webmaster Console and think I have located where the links are coming from ( microformats.org ) and there are 1000s of these links.

I am a newbie on the topic and would appreciate any input

[image: Google Console - Screen Shot 1]

Comment: There is nothing to do. 404 errors is exactly what should happen. You cannot stop other sites from linking to you and you cannot stop junk traffic. You can, however, keep letting your server respond with 404 errors like it should. It does not hurt anything. It is the way things are supposed to work. Just let it go. It will all settle down at some point. All will be fine. Cheers!!

Comment: Closetnoc is right when Google see new links and it returns 404, then Google will drop that automatically in few weeks.  So Just wait 2 weeks, then click mark as all fixed, and you will know Google has drop most of 404 links error from your search console.

Comment: Your site may have been hacked to create these pages which were then picked up by other sites.   Check your site for malware.

Answer (score 1):

Even when you have deleted the malware from your site the fact that in effect additional pages where made available on your site those pages will have been detected by search engine crawlers and will have been linked to by third party sites. These requests will continue to come through for as long as those links exist on the third party sites or the search engines. The only thing that you can do is to have the non existent URL's return a 404 not found error (proper 404 header not a soft 404).